# Facebook - Dashboard issues, counter resets after reloading page

Tags: facebook, count, counter, dashboard, bookmarks

I have a strange bug with bookmark counts - if I set/inc. the bookmark count of my app (with dashboard.setCount or .incrementCount), the bookmark count shows up in the users profile after the app name in the bookmarks section. Unfortunately, if the user reloads facebook or simply leaves facebook, without clicking on the bookmark, and coming back to facebook, the bookmark count has vanished. Although, if I call .getCount, it still says the right number (like the count didn't change).

This is really bad, because this is the only way (apart from eMail which i dont use) how my app can notify the user.

Comment: I answered a very similar question yesterday: [Facebook Counter Notification Vanish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868633/facebook-counter-notification-vanish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Requests 2.0 ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests ) you can send requests from the app to the user, as well as from users to other users.

With this, there's a migration setting in your app settings called 'Upgrade to Requests 2.0'.
If this setting is enabled, the bookmark will always be set to the current number of outstanding requests for that user [both requests sent by other users, and those sent by the app directly]. Overriding the number manually won't work in that case.