# Facebook counter notification vanish

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `setCount` to set the number of my Facebook app counter notification.

For example, I run `setCount` with `count = 33` and then my facebook page immediately changes and looks like this:

[image]

But, when refreshing facebook.com, the `33` is vanished and I got:

[image]

Using `getCount` I can see that my counter is still at `33`, but the number `33` is vanished from my facebook page.

Is this a Facebook bug? Any ideas what could be happenning?

I tried this to Chromium, Opera and Firefox. But I got the same results:

> using `setCount` the counter appears, but with just one refresh the
>   counter vanish

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That counter is maintained based on the number of active requests to a user from the application ([Facebook Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/)). After a short period of time the actual number of requests is requeried and the true value updated.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You mean, I'm misusing `getCount` and `setCount` ?

Comment: I think so. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to inform users about something new that happened in my app and that concerns them. In order to do so, I use `setCount` to show a number near the application name. Suppose a user will see this, will get in the app, will find the new information, then I will reset the counter back to 0.

Comment: There are some PHP examples on the [Facebook Developers Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) page that do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: There's a migration setting in the Deeveloper App called 'Upgrade to Requests 2.0' - if this is enabled the counter will be the number of outstanding requests, otherwise you can set it manually using getCount and setCount